# MAC Address doubt

Tags: mac-address

I have a lan device with the IP 192.168.1.10 connected to a Linksys E2000 router running DD-WRT with the IP 192.168.1.1 This router is configured as following, WAN Connection Type: Automatic DHCP.

This router then is connected to another router provided by my ISP, the IP is 192.168.1.254. This last router is connected to a Optical Network Terminal.

My question is, when I arp in 192.168.1.10, only 192.168.1.1 replies. Because all devices connected to it are in it's broadcast domain, so it's normal it can't see 192.168.1.254 right?

Also does the MAC address of 192.168.1.10 is seen in 192.168.1.254? Or for exemple if I visit Google.com, does Google servers see this device MAC? Is the MAC carried all along the circuit inside the frame?

Thanks, I hope my question isn't too confusing.

Comment: Don't use the same network for both sides of a NAT...

Answer (score 1):

The MAC address is seen only by the two segments connected to each other. So, Google would not be able to see you MAC address. Furthermore, it is appropriate that your firewall would ARP with it's MAC address for the .254 address, because all devices need to first go through the firewall before they can reach the ISP gateway. If 192.168.1.10 saw the real ARP address for 192.168.1.254, then you would wind up with either a loop, the firewall dropping that traffic or your firewall being rendered useless.